# Facebook Login with API

Tags: facebook, api, authentication

I am using the code below to login via facebook, it just happens that returns the name, does not return the email client're logged in, the only time he returns the email is if I enter email and password account on facebook who has created the application.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<script>
    FB.init({
        appId      : 'XXXXXXXXXXXX',
        status     : true,
        cookie     : true,
        xfbml      : true
    });

    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function(response) {
        if (response.status === 'connected') {
            FB.api('/me?fields=id,name,email', function(response) { 
                alert('Name is: '+response.name+'     Email is: '+response.email);

            });
        } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
          FB.login();
        } else {
            //$('#nome').html(null);
        }
    });
</script>
```

Result of the alert () when I run the above code.

When I log in using the account that I created the app.

**"Name is: Anderson Nun ... Email is: free...l@hotmail.com"**

When I login with any email account of any other client.

**"Name is: Name Customer ... Email is: undefined"**

As I understand I need to compare the email in my database and make the session login on my system, but email clients not being returned by facebook. How to proceed?

Comment: You’re not asking for the necessary _permission_ to read the user’s email during login …

Comment: But how do I do that? I thought I was asking permission when use /me?fields=id,name,email

Comment: That is asking for the actual data. And how to ask for permissions is clearly described in the login documentation – so go read it please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's right, I was just missing permission on the login button. Sufficed add the tag "email" that worked.